# How do I find the sum of a variable in JQuery that has multiple answers?

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables

I'm trying to get and display ticket prices based on the number of tickets a user wants to buy. When I run my code it does exactly what I want at first but the second number overrides the first, how do I add them together?

HTML:

```
     <ul id="tickets" class="clearfix registration-form"> 
            <li class="clearfix">
                <input type="hidden" id="ticket-price" value="90">
                <input class="short-input alpha number-tickets" type="number" placeholder="0" rel="#ticket-price">
                <label>Number of Tickets ($90 each)<p>This is some further information about tickets, and this can be as much information as you want it to be!</p></label>
            </li>
            <li class="clearfix">
                 <input type="hidden" id="ticket-price_2" value="35">
                 <input class="short-input alpha number-tickets" type="number" placeholder="0" rel="#ticket-price_2">
                 <label>Number of Tickets ($35 each)<p>This is some further information about tickets, and this can be as much information as you want it to be!</p></label>
            </li>
            <li class="tickets-total">
                 <label>Current Total = $</label>
                 <input id="ticketsTotal" type="number" placeholder="0.00" readonly="true">
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('input.number-tickets').keyup(function() {
    $('#tickets li input[type=number]')
            .not('#tickets li.tickets-total input[type=number]')
            .each(function(i, data) {
                var total = 0;
                var priceTotal = $(this).val() * $($(this).attr('rel')).val();

                for (var i=0; i < priceTotal.length; i++) {
                     total += priceTotal[i] << 0;
               }

               $('input#ticketsTotal').val(total);
    })
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the total variable (counter) outside of the **$.each** loop. As you have it now, you are setting the variable to 0 each time your loop runs.

```
var total = 0;
$('#tickets li input[type=number]')
    .not('#tickets li.tickets-total input[type=number]')
    .each(function (i, data) {
    var priceTotal = $(this).val() * $($(this).attr('rel')).val();

    for (var i = 0; i < priceTotal.length; i++) {
        total += priceTotal[i] << 0;
    }

    $('input#ticketsTotal').val(total);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much this has been stressing me out and I'm really glad it was so simple! - BTW if you couldn't tell this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input.number-tickets').keyup(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('#tickets li input[type=number]')
        .not('#tickets li.tickets-total input[type=number]')
        .each(function (i, data) {
        var priceTotal = $(this).val() * $($(this).attr('rel')).val();

        for (var i = 0; i < priceTotal.length; i++) {
            total += priceTotal[i] << 0;
        }

        $('input#ticketsTotal').val(total);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the old value like

```
$('input#ticketsTotal').val(parseInt($('input#ticketsTotal').val()) + total);
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you are doing here but can you tell me the significance of using the old value vs. just inserting the total the way I am?

Comment: I am simply adding the values in every iteration of `.each` loop. It is same as taking `var total` outside of the loop but instead of keeping the sum in `total` I am keeping it in `$('input#ticketsTotal').val()`

Comment: I get what you are doing, but why? Why does it matter where the math is being done, is it a speed issue? The way I've written it it's working perfectly fine, but if this is a better practice or something then I want to know what the purpose is. Thanks.

Comment: It is just another way of doing things. I am not suggesting that my method is better than the other answer. It is just another way of solving the same problem.